# Unable to run gwt project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

i am using gwt 2.5.1 and gae 1.7.5 and all of a sudden started getting following exception

Loading modules
   src.vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.AdminModule
      Loading inherited module 'src.vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.AdminModule'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'src/vik/sakshum/sakshumweb/AdminModule.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

on going to project properties under google --> gwt i can see this module. So, no idea whats the issue. plz advise

Comment: Are you using maven & eclipse or just eclipse.

Comment: Admin module should be in classPath. Are you using maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check entry point of module.xml. it should be proper like

```
<entry-point class='vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.AdminModule'/>
```

Also check run config parameter.  Do Right click of project-> **run configuration**->**Arguments**

it should be like this:

-startupUrl index.html -war {**path of project**}  -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 **vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.AdminModule**